# Updated Galaxy Note 8 to 4.2.2: can't pair with Bluetooth devices afterwards

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-note, bluetooth-pairing

With the previous version, 4.1.2, no problem to discover and pair with my Bluetooth speakers. However, after 4.2.2 upgrade, the Note 8 cannot find them when scanning. My phone, a Galaxy S4,(version 4.3), can however discover my Note and the speakers.

Note that the "multi-window" option was also greyed out after the upgrade, and only a factory reset could get it activated again.
Can't find a similar question on this forum so are there any ideas before I revert to a previous version.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the problem was resolved by doing a second factory reset. Looks like it's wise to do the factory reset several times before declaring the problem. Do this before setting up your screens with your widgets etc. organised and make sure you have a backup.